# Returning IDs list of entities with specified value without defined entity/POJO

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a method that returns me IDs (as a List ) of all records from a collection that have a certain status.
I am looking for a solution, but unfortunately I cannot find anything correct.
I currently have something like this:

```
List<String> getAllLecturersIdList() {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection.mongoTemplate.getCollection("lecturers");
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    ArrayList<String> listOfIDS = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        listOfIDS.add(cursor.next().getObjectId("_id").toString());
    }
    return listOfIDS;

}
```

This method returns me a list of IDs of all lecturers.
The lecturer entity also has a "status" field with values like ACTIVE, LEAVE, FIRED and so on.
I would like to have only IDs of lecturers who have ACTIVE status to be returned to me.
How to do it to have only entities with ACTIVE status when returning from the collection, and not to clean the repository / services level?
Thanks for help in advance!
Important - I don't want an entity structure to be created in the application.
Therefore, the solution cannot contain a POJO / Entity Class and here is the problem (I cannot use e.g. Criteria, because every example is with defined entity )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fallback to the low level `MongoOperations#executeQuery` method if there is no result type mapping your query results:

```
List<String> getAllLecturersIdList() {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.fields().include("_id");
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is("ACTIVE"));
    ArrayList<String> listOfIDS = new ArrayList<>();
    mongoTemplate.executeQuery(query, "lecturers", document -> listOfIDS.add(document.getObjectId("_id").toString()));
    return listOfIDS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```java
List<String> getAllLecturersIdList() {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection.mongoTemplate.getCollection("lecturers");
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    ArrayList<String> listOfIDS = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document document = cursor.next();
        if (document.getString("status") == "ACTIVE") {
          listOfIDS.add(document.getObjectId("_id").toString());
        }
    }
    return listOfIDS;
}
```